# Set path using if / else

Tags: conditionals, paths, ifthenelse

Depending on the previous text I need to set e path to folder 1 or folder 2.
With just one folder everything worked fine, but with the condition it doesn't. What am I missing?

```
\newcommand{\nc}{text-a}

\ifthenelse{\equal{\nc}{text-a}}
{
    \makeatletter
    \def\input@path{{"../folder-1/"}}
    \makeatother
}{
    \makeatletter
    \def\input@path{{"../folder-2/"}}
    \makeatother
}
```

edit: unfortunately it does not go this way either:

```
\newcommand{\nc}{text-a}

\makeatletter
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\nc}{text-a}}{
       \def\input@path{{"../folder-1/"}}
    }{   \def\input@path{{"../folder-2/"}}
    }
\makeatother
```

Comment: Did you try moving the `\makeatletter` *before* the `\ifthenelse{\equal{\nc}{text-a}}` and the `\makeatother` to after the entire block (I didn't test this suggestion for lack of an MWE)? IIRC the category code can't be changed within arguments of macros, this has to be done 'outside'.

Comment: @moewe Yes, I already tried to do it like this but I got the same problems.

Comment: @GuestUser `\makeatletter` can not work inside the argument of a command (same reason as `\verb` not working there)  move them outside

Comment: @DavidCarlisle unfortunately it does not go this way either.

Comment: @GuestUser that sets the path, if that path does not work then you have an error in code not shown

Answer (score 2):

The posted code does set the path conditionally, the test file below shows both settings:

---

```
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
> \input@path=macro:
->{"../folder-1/"}.
l.13 \show\input@path

? 
> \input@path=macro:
->{"../folder-2/"}.
l.26 \show\input@path

? 
 )
No pages of output.
```

---

```
\RequirePackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\nc}{text-a}

\makeatletter
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\nc}{text-a}}{
       \def\input@path{{"../folder-1/"}}
    }{   \def\input@path{{"../folder-2/"}}
    }
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\show\input@path
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\nc}{text-b}

\makeatletter
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\nc}{text-a}}{
       \def\input@path{{"../folder-1/"}}
    }{   \def\input@path{{"../folder-2/"}}
    }
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\show\input@path
\makeatother



\stop
```